# Validation to Forms with Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am new to Python and currently working with Flask WTForms.

I have created a user login page as shown below:
[image]

As seen in the image, the "Sign Up" button is pushed on the side to create space for the red notification.

However, I want the notification to appear on the side of the box as shown in the image below:
[image]

How to I go about it?

Here is my code:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    user_email = EmailField(label='Email', validators=[DataRequired()])
    user_password = PasswordField('Password', [
        validators.DataRequired(message='Password is required.'),
        validators.Length(message='Password must be at least 8 characters long.', min=8)
    ])
    submit = SubmitField(label='Sign Up')
```

```
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    login_form.validate_on_submit()
    return render_template('login.html', form=login_form)
```

Below is the login.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Login</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="{{url_for('login')}}" novalidate>
            {{ form.csrf_token }}
            <p>{{ form.user_email.label }} <br> {{ form.user_email(size=30) }}</p>
            {% if form.user_email.errors %}
                <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.user_email.errors %}</ul>
                        <span style="color:red" >{{ error}}</span>
                    {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            <p>{{ form.user_password.label }} <br> {{ form.user_password(size=30) }}</p>
            {% if form.user_password.errors %}
                <ul class="errors">{% for error in form.user_password.errors %}</ul>
                    <span style="color:red" >{{ error}}</span>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
            {{form.submit}}
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll need to change your template. Edit your question to include `login.html`.

Comment: @Henry I have added the login.html.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `login.html` form to something like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{url_for('login')}}" novalidate>
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    <p>
        {{ form.user_email.label }} <br>
        {{ form.user_email(size=30) }}
        {% if form.user_email.errors %}
            <span style="color:red" >{{ form.user_email.errors | join(',') }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    </p>
    
    <p>
        {{ form.user_password.label }} <br>
        {{ form.user_password(size=30) }}
        {% if form.user_password.errors %}
            <span style="color:red" >{{ form.user_password.errors | join(',') }}</span>
        {% endif %}
    </p>
    {{form.submit}}
</form>
```

The error `span` is now inside the `p`, so will be displayed inline. Instead of looping through the errors, I've used the `join` filter to join them with commas.